# Perl can't get variable from module, but can call functions

Tags: perl, module

I have some silly mistake due to inexperiance which I can't find by myself. I have a module `TestMod` which I have included into a file. I have access to the functions of `TestMod`, though I can't get to the variables. My question is why isn't it working.

Here is the module:

```
package TestMod;
use strict;

my $some_var = "lalalala";

sub GetVar()
{
    return "something";
}

1;
```

The script:

```
use strict;
use lib "/home/user2121/projects/";
use module;
my $a = TestMod::GetVar();
print "$a\n\n$TestMod::some_var\n";
```

my output is:

```
something
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) instead of [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html):

```
our $some_var = "lalalala";
```

Comment: That's the answer, thanks. I will accept this when the timer expires.

Comment: @Bloodcount Thanks! I'm still kind of surprised I remember some Perl stuff ;)

Comment: The explanation is that `my` declares a lexical variable, so the variable is only visible within a block or a file. `our` puts the variable in the namespace, so it can be accesses from other scopes.

Comment: It's probably not something you should do, though. An accessor is probably called for.

Answer (score 0):

Based off your `use module;` call, it's apparent that you aren't using packages entirely right.

Make it so that your packages and their file share the same name.  For example, `package TestMod;` should be in the file `TestMod.pm`.

Then when you want to use the package you just need to call `use TestMod;`

Additionally, you can use [`Exporter`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) to enable the exporting of variables and functions to other namespaces.  Utilizing this functionality would change your package to the following:

```
package TestMod;
use strict;

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw($some_var GetVar);

our $some_var = "lalalala";

sub GetVar {
    return "something";
}

1;
```

And then your main perl script would be modified to the following:

```
use strict;
use lib "/home/user2121/projects/";
use TestMod qw(GetVar $some_var);
my $a = GetVar();
print "$a\n\n$some_var\n";
```